# Как правильно: чернЮщий или чернУщий?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

Как правильно:

> черн**ю**щий или черн**у**щий

в значении очень-очень чёрный?

Само слово не нашёл ни в одном словаре. Насколько это литературная форма или лучше употреблять только в разговорной речи?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Форма, конечно, разговорная, поэтому и в словаре нет. 
Но вообще суффикс высшей степени качества проявляется в двух вариантах: "-ющ" и "-ущ", из которых вариант "ущ" - и только он - бывает всегда после шипящих и Ц, а в остальных случаях только как второй (хитрющий и хитрущий, худющий и худущий) - и далеко не всегда. У слов злющий, вреднющий и других альтернативного варианта нет.

Получается, что вариант ***чернющий*** - беспроигрышный, а *чернущий* - сомнителен. Но, как уже говорил, оба максимум - разговорные.